# numpy.core.umath error when importing keras in python3

Tags: python, keras

When I ran import keras in python it returns this error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
RuntimeError                              
Traceback (most recent call
last) RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xb
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ImportError                               
Traceback (most recent call last) ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ImportError                               
Traceback (most recent call last) ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ImportError                               
Traceback (most recent call last) ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
```

And a pop-up window will show Python **quit unexpectedly**. What do I need to do here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xb

Make sure you are using an acceptable numpy version.